# MySQL TEXT memory allocation

Tags: mysql, memory

Anybody knows how MySQL allocates disk space for fields like "TEXT" or "BLOB"

For example, what happens when I insert 10kb string into "TEXT" column? Is the entire 65kb data allocated or only 10kb?

Comment: Don't confuse limits with the space allocated. `VARCHAR(255)` holds a maximum of 255 characters. There are some types which *do* reserve space, like `CHAR`, but these are the exception.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is explained in the documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html

```
BLOB, TEXT              L + 2 bytes, where L < 2^16
MEDIUMBLOB, MEDIUMTEXT  L + 3 bytes, where L < 2^24 
LONGBLOB, LONGTEXT      L + 4 bytes, where L < 2^32
```

> Variable-length string types are stored using a length prefix plus
>   data. The length prefix requires from one to four bytes depending on
>   the data type, and the value of the prefix is L (the byte length of
>   the string). For example, storage for a MEDIUMTEXT value requires L
>   bytes to store the value plus three bytes to store the length of the
>   value.

So in short, the whole 65kb is not wasted.